# jQuery Mobile - List slips under header

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am currently working on a web app for mobile phones and tablets and got to another problem with jquery mobile. my header is fixed to the top an i have got to lists that are under it. the left one is positioned relative the right one absolute.

the left one slips under my header. the scrolling is active, although there is no need to scroll actually.

does someone have a hint?

[image: example]

```
<div id="page" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active ui-page-header-fixed" data-role="page" data-url="page" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 491px; padding-top: 44px;">
    <div id="content" class="ui-content" data-role="content" role="main">
        <div class="ui-header ui-bar-a ui-header-fixed slidedown" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" role="banner">
        <ul id="console" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="width: 50%;">
        <ul id="control" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-inset="true" data-role="listview" style="width: 48%; position: fixed; top: 58px; right: 1%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Here you have got a print out of my firebug console:

[image]

EDIT 2:

The strange thing is the size of the html element:

[image]

Comment: interesting... perhaps it would be worth reproducing this on http://jsfiddle.net and reporting it to JQM directly

Comment: @tellob Are all the div tags closed?

Comment: It would be interesting to see your source, because it looks like you are posting the post-jQueryMobile modified divs, which don't tell us as much.  At any rate, your right-hand UL has a fixed top, which I guessing if you left off it would do the same as the left-hand side.  I see this behavior all the time, usually at the bottom of lists when I try to put something underneath.  I don't know the "real" solution but if you have a "clear:all" style on the element, it will show up in the proper place.

Answer (score 0):

You have a header at a wrong position, it should not be a part of a content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page" data-role="page" data-url="page" >
        <div class="ui-header ui-bar-a ui-header-fixed slidedown" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" role="banner">
            <h3>Header</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="content" data-role="content">
            <ul id="console" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="width: 50%;">
                <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="control" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-inset="true" data-role="listview" style="width: 48%; position: fixed; top: 58px; right: 1%;">
                <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/us2w5/

Comment: did not help, but thanks for seeing this mistake. maybe i can reproduce it on jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n8jNx/3/ This is the base of my code. Maybe its because im using backbone.js in the background?

Comment: I dont think so, backbone should not cause css problems, unless you are using backbone for content generation.

Comment: In my console view im just doing things like: 
tagName : 'ul',
  id : 'console',
  
  attributes : {
   'data-role' : 'listview',
   'data-inset' : 'true'
  },

  consoleTemplate : _.template($('#console-template').html()),

Comment: i added another screenshot ;)

Comment: my page div always gets a min-height css attribute by default and this seems to be to big..?! the difference seems to be exactly the header size.

Comment: i could fix it with calling a $(window).resize();. but there is still coming a scroll bar. dont know why.

Comment: It looks like your header and content are overlapping. What is tha slidedown class in your header?

Comment: This is the headers div tag: <div class="ui-header ui-bar-a ui-header-fixed slidedown" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" role="banner"> ... I dont know where the slidedown class comes from!